# NextJs 13: child route elements not removed when navigating back to parent

Tags: next.js, next.js13

As suggested in the Next 13 docs, I've used a route segment to open a modal (note the URL).
[image: screen cap of localhost/add]
The problem is that when I navigate away, the modal doesn't go away.
[image: screen cap of localhost]

If I manually close it on submit, then it doesn't reopen when I navigate to the route again.

Here's the code in add/page:

```
'use client';
import {useCallback, useEffect, useRef} from "react";
import {addMe} from "./actions";
import './add-user.css';
import {useRouter} from "next/navigation";

export default async function AddFriend() {
  const modalRef = useRef<HTMLDialogElement>(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (modalRef.current && !modalRef.current.open) {
      modalRef.current.showModal();
    }
  }, [modalRef.current]);

  const router = useRouter();

  const closeMe = useCallback(() => {
    router.replace('/');
    //if (modalRef.current?.open)  modalRef.current.close();
  }, [modalRef.current]);

  return (
    <dialog ref={modalRef} id="add-user">
      <form action={addMe} onSubmit={() => closeMe()}>
        <h2>Create New Friend</h2>
        <label>First Name
          <input type="text" id="first_name" name="first_name" autoComplete="off" required />
        </label>
        <label>Last Name
          <input type="text" id="last_name" name="last_name" autoComplete="off" required />
        </label>
        <button>Create Friend</button>
      </form>
    </dialog>
  )
}
```

I also have another issue related to building things as the docs suggest, which is I can't find how to refresh the list of friends when navigating back to the root url, even if I set the fetch to revalidate. I think maybe I'm missing something about how to do navigation here?